# Java pattern to use for processing messages with multiple XML schemas

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jms

I have a Java program that listens to a queue.  The messages on the queue are in XML format.  But each message could have a different schema.  I want my program to read messages and pass control to appropriate processors depending on the schema.  Is it possible to do this?  If yes, what Java pattern should I use?  Some pseudo code would be really helpful.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, what? This question is a bit broad, I think.

Answer (score 0):

A full XML parse is expensive for mere dispatching.  Sniffing is a less expensive alternative.  Consider instead, however, the use of a message header or message property to convey sufficient information for dispatching to occur without requiring direct inspection of the XML.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the producer, let the producer set a value to the JMSType JMS property with the kind of message that the payload represent, then after receiving the message, test this property then handle the payload as it should be.
Another option is to generate JAXB classes from the xsd (schema) of all the possible xml payload you can receive, then create a JAXBContext that can handle all the "jaxb root classes" corresponding to the possible payloads, unmarshall the payload and test the class of the object created by the unmarshaller:
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class,B.class,C.class);  Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller(); Object o = u.unmarshal(payload text from message); if (o instance of A.class) ...